# Run a silent batch command on Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a `.bat` file to run some programs (Apache httpd, Tomcat, ecc.). These programs have their own window and if I just type this into the `.bat` file:

```
../apache/bin/httpd.exe
../tomcat/bin/catalina.exe
...
```

When this runs I get many prompt windows, how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>Add at the beginning of the batch file:</strike>

`@echo off`

The commands in the Batch file would actually be `start`

`start /B ../apache/bin/httpd.exe`

`start /B ../tomcat/bin/catalina.exe`

http://ss64.com/nt/start.html

> /B         : Start application without creating a new window. In this case ^C will be ignored - leaving ^Break as the only way to interrupt the application

Comment: Wow, I think you completely misunderstood the question, and obviously so did the upvoters. The way I see it each EXE is launching a new cmd window and *that's* what he wants to prevent.

Comment: @Karan  You're right.  Fixed with the actual command.

Comment: It is quite perfect... Is it possibile to store in some way that process session to send a term signal? I would like to stop apache and tomcat if the main (and lonely) windonw will be closed. Thanks

Comment: @Tobia I have not used the `start` command myself, nor have I done much batch scripting.  Sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this problem is to use CHP
http://www.commandline.co.uk/chp/

This program run an hidden process and return its PID by return code.
Than you can use this pid to close the process with taskkill.